How to trim a string by the nth occurrence of a special character?
I have string values (filed name: filename) that follow a certain template:
filename_this_is_called_Plan_A
file_this_is_Plan_A
filename2024_this_is_known_as_Plan_A

While the strings are all a different length, they all end with _Plan_A, also known as the segment.
How can I trim this in PostgreSQL in order to always trim the string by the third to last underscore? Basically, so my table looks something like this



filename
segment




filename_this_is_called_Plan_A
Plan_A


file_this_is_Plan_A
Plan_A



I've tried a lot of different things, but have trouble getting that nth character.
select
filename,
right(filename, charindex('_', reverse(filename)) -1),
count(1)from table
group by 1,2

Output will typically be something like 'A' by itself when the desired output is Plan_A
Additionally, this can follow many naming conventions... Plan_A is example. There can be _Plan_B, _Plan_C, _File_C, etc.

Please provide some more examples with expected results? what does trimming the string by the third to last underscore mean? Include some examples from other segments: do they always follow _xxxx_x pattern (because you said _Plan_B, _Plan_C, _File_C, .etc.)

The title asks for the "nth occurrence of a special character", then you declare "all end with _Plan_A", then you ask to "trim by the third to last underscore", which matches neither. Finally you show different endings without formulating a question to make the confusion perfect. What a ride. Can you zoom in on one question?

The use of charindex would suggest it's Microsoft SQL Server rather than Postgres.

If your file name is always after the penultimate (second to last) underscore in the string - then you could use something like below. This code will do the job (using just the basic string functions) regardless the length of the specific name and/or suffix and regardless the number of underscores before the name.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl ( ID Int, FILE_NAME Varchar(64) );
Insert Into tbl VALUES
( 1, 'filename_this_is_called_Plan_A' ),
( 2, 'file_this_is_Plan_A' ), 
( 3, 'filename2024_this_is_known_as_Plan_A' ), 
( 4, 'filename2024_this_could_be_Whatever_BCDE' );

Select    ID, FILE_NAME,
          SUBSTR(  SubStr(FILE_NAME, 1, SUFFIX_POSITION - 1), 
                   Length( SubStr( FILE_NAME, 1, SUFFIX_POSITION - 1 ) ) - 
                          Position('_' In Reverse(SubStr(FILE_NAME, 1, SUFFIX_POSITION - 1))) + 2 
                ) || SUFFIX as FNAME 
From ( Select   tbl.*, 
                SubSTr( FILE_NAME, Length(FILE_NAME) - Position('_' In Reverse(FILE_NAME)) + 1 ) as SUFFIX, 
                Length(FILE_NAME) - Position('_' In Reverse(FILE_NAME)) + 1 as SUFFIX_POSITION
       From   tbl
     )

/*      R e s u l t :
id  file_name                                      fname
--  ---------------------------------------------  -----------------
1   filename_this_is_called_Plan_A                 Plan_A
2   file_this_is_Plan_A                            Plan_A
3   filename2024_this_is_known_as_Plan_A           Plan_A
4   filename2024_this_could_be_Whatever_BCDE       Whatever_BCDE    */

See the fiddle here.
